# angular property to have a different names on mobile and tablet versions

Tags: angular

I want to rewrite that code more efficiently. The code works, but I want to know if there's a way to 'buttonText' is '+' while mobile, and while tab or desktop, it's '+ Add New Task'.

header.component.html

```
<div class="w-12 block md:hidden">
            <app-button buttonBg="#635FC7" buttonText="+" buttonTextSize="1"></app-button>
        </div>
        <div class="w-40 hidden md:block">
            <app-button buttonBg="#635FC7" buttonText="+ Add New Task" buttonTextSize="1"></app-button>
        </div>
```

button.component.html

```
<button [class]="buttonTextSize === '1' ? 'text-2xl': 'text-[15px]'" class="rounded-[20px] flex justify-center text-white w-full h-10 font-bold leading-normal font-WebFont" [style.background-color]="buttonBg">{{buttonText}}</button>
```

button.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.css']
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() public buttonText = "";
  @Input() public buttonBg = "";
  @Input() public buttonTextSize = "";
  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
}
```

I don't have an idea what to try

Comment: You can check`window.innerWidth` in your button component and have it handle its own text based on that, no need for parent to send the values.